# Getting an error in in the anuglar component html file : Cannot find control with path

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

Hi I am new to angular and currently i am getting an error as below. Really appreciate any help if you can throw some lights on this.

```
GlobalSettingsComponent.html:66 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'tagonSettings -> tagonSettingFormGroup -> tagonType'
    at _throwError (forms.js:2432)
    at setUpControl (forms.js:2300)
    at FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.js:6664)
    at FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.js:7314)
    at FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.js:7227)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12348)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13876)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:13819)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:14712)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14653)
```

So following is what i am trying to do . I am having a form group and it has form arrays in it as below

```
this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
      inventories: this.fb.array([]),
      flightRates: this.fb.array([]),
      settings: this.fb.array([]),
      tagonSettings: this.fb.array([])
    });
```

in the tagonSettings form array i am trying to create and push  an instance of FormGroup as below. the reason i am pushing a formgroup because i need to group a few controls.

```
this.globalTagonSettingsArray.push(
  new FormGroup({
      id : new FormControl( globalTagonSetting.id ),
      tagonText: new FormControl(globalTagonSetting.tagonText, [Validators.required] ),
      tagonType: new FormControl(globalTagonSetting.tagonType, [Validators.required] )
    }
  )
);
```

in my component html i am doing the following.

```
 <div class="form-title mb-3 mt-3">{{ 'HEADINGS.ADDITIONAL_TAGON_SETTINGS' | translate }}</div>
    <div formArrayName="tagonSettings">
        <div class="row" *ngFor="let tagonSettingFormGroup of globalTagonSettingsArray.controls; let i = index">
          <div formGroupName="tagonSettingFormGroup">
            <div class="col-4">
                <input formControlName="tagonText">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <input formControlName="tagonType">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Please remove your unnecessary codes

Comment: which one should i remove ?

Comment: There are unnecessary codes in the whole page. Post here what exactly you need with the necessary codes

Comment: I usually use `<form *ngIf="formGroup" [formGroup]="formGroup"...>` to avoid initial errors

Comment: You have to include a `<form [formGroup]="formGroup">` around the inputs for it to work, formControlName only accesses input that are inside a formGroup

Comment: yes just now got it correct . do you want post the answer .?

Answer (score 0):

i should have added formGroup]="tagonSettingFormGroup". now it started to work.

```
<div class="form-title mb-3 mt-3">{{ 'HEADINGS.ADDITIONAL_TAGON_SETTINGS' | translate }}</div>
    <div formArrayName="tagonSettings">
        <div class="row" *ngFor="let tagonSettingFormGroup of globalTagonSettingsArray.controls; let i = index">
          <div [formGroup]="tagonSettingFormGroup" >
            <div class="col-4">
                <input formControlName="tagonText">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <input formControlName="tagonType">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4"></div>
          </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```